# Unable to Connect to Remote WCF Service - SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: c#, wcf

I am starting off with [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation), and I am following [the samples from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483346.aspx). I managed to run the Getting Started sample on one machine as well as by deploying the client & service on separate machines and remotely accessing the service.

My goal is to implement the [Publish/Subscribe design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx). I have managed to run it on one machine without any big issues. But when I am deploying client & service on different machine, my client is unable to connect to the service. I get the following exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException was unhandled
  Message=The caller was not authenticated by the service.
  Source=mscorlib
```

(I can share the stack trace if necessary.)

Here are my configurations:

**Service - web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Client - app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_ISampleContract" clientBaseAddress="http://<SERVICE MACHINE PUBLIC IP>:8000/myClient/"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                  openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://<SERVICE MACHINE PUBLIC IP>/ServiceModelSamples/service.svc"
          binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ISampleContract"
          contract="ISampleContract" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ISampleContract">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/<SERVICE MACHINE PUBLIC IP>" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have searched for a solution, but nothing has worked for me. I have tried to find a way to disable the security/authentication on the service side (just to get it work), but haven't been successful in that as well.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is <SERVICE MACHINE PUBLIC IP> in your configuration actually set?

Comment: @ValtasarIII Yes sir. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[wsDualHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731821%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default uses Windows authentication. If you don't need this authentication for now, you can change your configuration to switch it off:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpDual">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpDual"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The same way change security section in client configuration:

```
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

Comment: Just a small problem in the above code. wsDualHttpBinding does not support Transport Security. So the above configurations would be correct if we use them without the transport security. Rest is fine and seems to be working for me now.

Comment: I have tried this but now i am receiving this error "The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.7710000. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.". Please suggest something.